# PowerShell based SQL script execution

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am new to powershell. Even I dont think I know the basics..But now I am assigned a work to do the execution of sql scripts residing in a remote server.

1) we have to connect to that particular database/server using ip and the credentials--For this I need powershell to ask user to give the required parameters(such like server/database name/ip and credentials)

2) The next step is to get the sql scripts from 3 different folders based on 3 different inputs from user--Here I need powershell to ask user to enter the parameters(Eg:a=1st folder, m=2nd folder and x=3rd folder)

3) Then the execution of the script.After the execution, then it should again ask user to continue or exit.

The 3 steps described above is my requirement. Someone please help on this..Any help would be really appreciated..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This question seems overly broad for dba, please read http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @JamesJenkins Not sure I can agree with that comment.  The OP is quite explicit in what he/she is looking for and wants to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note: Before I get into sample code on one way to go about this, I recommend you make every attempt at grasping the programmatic interaction between SQL Server and PowerShell.  It is not hard, and by muscling through a few scripts from given requirements like the ones above your proficiency will exponentially grow.**

> 1) we have to connect to that particular database/server using ip and the credentials--For this I need powershell to ask user to give the required parameters(such like server/database name/ip and credentials)

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll"

$SqlServerName = Read-Host "Server name"

$SqlServer = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($SqlServerName)

$SqlServer.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = $false

$SqlServer.ConnectionContext.Login = Read-Host "Login"
$SqlServer.ConnectionContext.SecurePassword = Read-Host "Password" -AsSecureString
```

> 2) The next step is to get the sql scripts from 3 different folders based on 3 different inputs from user--Here I need powershell to ask user to enter the parameters(Eg:a=1st folder, m=2nd folder and x=3rd folder)

```
$SqlScripts = @()

while ($true) {
    $ScriptLocation = Read-Host "Enter location (""x"" if no more needed)"
    if ($ScriptLocation.ToLower() -eq "x") {
        break
    }
    $SqlScripts += $ScriptLocation
}
```

> 3) Then the execution of the script.After the execution, then it should again ask user to continue or exit.

```
foreach ($SqlScript in $SqlScripts) {
    try {
        $SqlServer.Databases["master"].ExecuteNonQuery((Get-Content -Path $SqlScript))
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error $_.Exception
    }
}
```

As for your last statement "After the execution, then it should again ask user to continue or exit", I'm not quite sure what you're looking to do there.  Ask the user to continue doing what?  Regardless, the above **sample** code should give you quite a head start on your requirement.  Test this logic out in a non-production environment to ensure it does what you want and rework accordingly.  There are a couple of assumptions here (such as you're not looking for a return from the script, which is why I used `ExecuteNonQuery()`, I don't know your databases layout so it's going to execute in the context of `master`, so on and so forth).

Comment: Many thanks for your valuable response and sample code. Really it gave me an idea on how to do it..Many Thanks Again..

After the execution in the sense,I have 3 folders having 3 types of sql scripts.I need to execute scripts inside 1st folder.Then I need powershell to show me errors(if any) and then ask user to continue with the next folder scripts.Hope this makes you sense..Also it should automatically sava a text file with those errors(if any)..

Any idea on how to achieve this??

Comment: In order to save the errors to a text file, instead of having `Write-Error $_.Exception` in the `CATCH{}` block, just have an `Out-File` cmdlet call and append to an error log of your choice.

Comment: Thanks thomas..When I try to execute the code it shows Cannot find type [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server]: make sure the assembly containing this type is l
oaded. Iam trying to load the dll like this..

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('D:\VysakhTest\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') | out-null

Am I doing anything wrong??There is no smo dll found in my server so i couldnt test my code.Please help me out on this..